# What are my exterior PV disconnect options?

Tags: electrical, solar

I am trying to decide on exterior PV disconnect details for a small PV array. (in Georgia, US) The array is estimated to produce roughly 23A @240V and will feed a 30A breaker using 10awg wire. The array cabling will terminate near the center of the roof, with the main panel just below.

My AHJ requires an external PV disconnect near the power meter on the side of the home. This location would require about 40' of additional wire to reach the disconnect, so ~80' round-trip to return to the panel.

I'm not certain if I should be concerned about the additional circuit length required from running the PV array output to the exterior disconnect and back to the panel. If so, should I consider placing a 30A 240V relay between the array and panel, and use a separate (smaller) circuit with the exterior disconnect to (de)energize the relay coil? I haven't purchased any of the disconnect system components yet, just trying to determine the best approach. Any suggestions/opinions from those more informed than me are appreciated!

Comment: 80 feet should only matter to your bank account.  I would cost out 8 gauge aluminum, to see if it is cheaper.

Comment: Your AHJ would be the one to tell you if they'll accept a relay-based shut off. I would suspect that the answer is likely "no", but that's just a gut feeling - not based on any particular code knowledge. I'd say it's a strong "no" if you're building it yourself, but a possible "yes" if you're buying a UL Certified system designed for what you're after. TL;DR: Ask the AHJ...

Comment: How can it be that your main panel is so far from your meter?  Normally that run must be as short as possible.  Is there a breaker in the meter pan?

Comment: @crip659, running 10 awg copper to the disconnect and back is more expensive, but simpler. Just wanted to make sure I'm not overlooking a better solution, though simple is probably better in this case.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica, the house is 65 years old so there are a lot of interesting features. For example, the main panel is in a bedroom closet!

Comment: Who is your electric utility? This may be a function of *them* even more so than the AHJ, and I can tell you right now that *most* utilities require a *visible blade* (read: safety switch) disconnect -- if a CB won't fly, anything relay based certainly won't stand a chance)